# Class App\Http\Controllers\AuthController does not exist Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

My whole application, made in Laravel 5.2, is working perfectly fine but when i tried to get list of routes through following command:

> php artisan route:list

It shows me following error:

> [ReflectionException]                                        Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\AuthController does not exist

i tried to add namespace aswell:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
    Route::auth();
});
```

then it shows me following error:

> [ReflectionException]
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth\AuthController does not exist

My routes file is:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'namespace'=>'Auth'], function() {
     Route::auth(); 
});
```

Update: content of Router.php

```
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    $this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
}
```

Please help! Thanks

Comment: remove 'namespace'=>'Auth', working ?

Comment: did you run the composer dump-autoload command?

Comment: The dump-autoload command updates information autoloader. This command is useful when you add new classes and do not want to run the install or update command

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment so I'm going to ask have you run `php artisan make:auth` and with laravel 5.2 you dont need your routes in your `Routes.php`. All you have to have in your `href="{{ url('/login') }}"`

Answer (score 2):

in my case just remove:

```
     'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
```

[image: namespace => App\Http\Controllers]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I found out what was the issue.
My code was look like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
namespace App\Repositories;
```

And I changed to this:

```
namespace App\Repositories;
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

Issue solved for me.

Comment: You only want one namespace declaration. This looks like the second declaration was overriding the first, until you switched them around. You only need one.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Just use

```
Route::get('/login',[
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login',
    'as'   => 'login'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.2 you can use `php artisan make:auth` , this creates a line

`Route::auth()` in your `routes.php` file. And creates all the necessary

routes.

Also your namespacing solution would probably work if you remove the `Auth` part from

`'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm'`

and leave it like

`'AuthController@showRegistrationForm'`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while trying to implement multi-auth with two registration forms in `Laravel 8.69`. My controller `AuthController` existed. While extending class controller my code read `class RegisterController extends Controller` instead of `class AuthController extends Controller`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).