# Laravel 5.2 - Method auth does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, composer-php, laravel-5

I recently cloned a Laravel 5.2 project. After running `composer install`, I keep getting the following error after every Artisan command and when trying to access the app:

> Method auth does not exist

I could find similar "method does not exist" issues online, but nothing about 'auth'. I believe the 'auth' class being referred to is the built-in one that can be used as middleware for various routes. However, I have no idea how to solve the issue.

I've tried:

- composer dump-autoload -o
- deleting the vendor libraries and reinstalling with composer
- resetting to the remote branch
- re-cloning the repository
- running under PHP 5.6 and 7.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My composer file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "gloudemans/calendar": "dev-master",
    "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "predis/predis": "~1.0",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
    "mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {

    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
} 
}
```

The error's stack trace from the laravel.log file:

> [2018-05-01 12:49:56] local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Method auth does not exist. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:81
>   Stack trace:
>
> 1. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(213): Illuminate\Routing\Router->__call('auth', Array)
> 2. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/app/Http/routes.php(424): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('auth', Array)
> 3. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(41): require('/Applications/X...')
> 4. [internal function]: App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->App\Providers{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router))
> 5. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(354): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router))
> 6. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(42): Illuminate\Routing\Router->group(Array, Object(Closure))
> 7. [internal function]: App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->map(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router))
> 8. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> 9. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(72): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
> 10. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->loadRoutes()
> 11. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(29): Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->boot(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router))
> 12. [internal function]: App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->boot(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router))
> 13. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> 14. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
> 15. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(717): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider))
>       15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation{closure}(Object(App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider), 16)
> 16. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(718): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
> 17. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
> 18. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
> 19. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(208): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
> 20. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(105): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
> 21. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/[ProjectName]/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> 22. {main}

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149442/class-app-http-controllers-authcontroller-does-not-exist-laravel-5-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: can you post your routes here? or those routes which are using middle ware auth

Comment: @prakashtank - I checked the link, doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @JagadeshaNH there are quite a few routes that use that, so it would be impractical to post them all here (I might create a gist for it).

However, I did notice the following route in the routes.php file:
 > Route::auth();

When I remove it I can now use Artisan again and the 'Method auth does not exist' error goes away. 

Instead, I get a different error. I'll check it and see if I can resolve it.

Comment: app/Http/routes.php(424) can you post whats there in line 424 of your routes.php

Comment: php artisan make:auth

Comment: @JagadeshaNH good catch, that's the line with the suspicious route:
Route::auth();

I'm guessing it creates a bunch of default routes related to authentication.

Comment: I get: "Command 'make:auth' is not defined". Maybe it was removed in Laravel 5.2?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php check line 298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JagadeshaNH I was able to resolve the issue.

The routes.php contained the following line:
Route::auth();

This calls to a function that generates a bunch of authentication routes.

After running `composer install` for the first time it apparently did not install all the version updates for Laravel 5.2, which contain the `php artisan make:auth` command and the actual `auth` function.

Because these files did not exist, artisan kept failing and the app wouldn't run.

The solution was:

1. Comment out `Route::auth()` in the routes.php file
2. Run `composer update` (which did not work before because of the error)
3. Uncomment `Route::auth()`

Answer (score 2):

Replace Route::auth() with the following routes, or

```
// Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: Thanks @JagadeshaNH, this would indeed add the missing routes that `Route::auth()` is supposed to generate, but would unlikely solve other problems related to missing core files. It was necessary to temporarily disable `Route::auth()` and use `composer update` for that.

Comment: yes, earlier versions of laravel didn't have Route:auth() method, so u can comment this line and update it, so that the error won't appear.

Answer (score -1):

try command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Comment: Please update your answer to include some explanation and/or link to documentation explaining why this is necessary.